# I want to sort table by column contains tags(HTML tags)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My table columns consists HTML tags. And in normal way sorting prefers tags first.
I want to ignore HTML tags while sorting

// Sample code
$data = $model->sortBy('name')->get();

Comment: strip_tags("Hello <b>world!</b>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby

```
$sorted = $data->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return strip_tags($item->name);
});
```